# How do I wait for Twitter trends to load before running code in Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to write a Chrome extension for Twitter, and want to modify the layout of the page a bit. I've tried a lot things and have googled around, but to no avail.

I want to add a div in between the trends and the footer. However, Twitter seems to generate those elements with ajax, so they don't exist when my code runs, even when in a $(document).ready function.

The only way I've gotten it to work is by putting my code in a setTimeout function for 1-2 seconds. This seems like a rather unreliable solution, so I would greatly appreciate any help with this problem.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking after each AJAX request if some DOM elements are in place is not much better than checking same thing every 1-2 sec with `setTimeout` (as you did).

Much better way to go is to use a [DOMNodeInserted](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-eventgroupings-mutationevents) event. If you set it up right (add it to the right element(s)) you will be notified whenever elements your are waiting for are inserted into DOM. After event is fired remember to remove it (`removeEventListener`) as mutation events are known for their [performance issues](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Mutation_events).

Comment: Sounds like just what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The way to do this is to create a background page and then call it using  `chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().`
 Once the ajax request is completed you can tweak your popup page. In case you have to send parameters to the background page then you would have to add listeners to the background page like this:

```
================
chrome.extension.sendRequest({greeting: "hello"}, function(response) {
  console.log(response.farewell);
});


===============
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
          sendResponse({farewell: "goodbye"});
  });
```

More information about message passing can be found at:[Message passing](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/messaging.html).

If you really do not want to do all this you can just call use the ajax request synchronously by setting the parameter to false.

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","url",false);
```

However this is not good practise and i would strongly advise against it.Hope this solves your problem!

Comment: There's no `synchronous` parameter to be set to `true`, you probably mean setting the `async` parameter to `false`. [See reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests).

Comment: I appreciate the help. I think I might not have communicated my question clearly enough. I'm not the one making an ajax request, but rather, Twitter itself is. I'm strictly modifying the way Twitter looks without using a popup page. I do plan to write another chrome extension soon though, so this will definitely be a great help in the future. Thanks!